# Initialize SharedWorker in its own process?

Tags: google-chrome, memory-management, shared-worker

I'm working on a web app that needs to load very large datasets on the browser, additionally, I also need to load a lot of data on a SharedWorker.

The current browsers (Chrome?) limitations set a limit of around 8GB of used memory for a single process/tab.

My app makes use of different windows (one for each computer's screen) and each of them is open with the `noopener` attribute to ensure a dedicated process is used. This allows each window to use 8GB rather than sharing the limit across pages.

Now I would need to also do the same for the SharedWorker, currently it shares the limits with whatever page spawns it.

The only solution I found is to open a `noopener` popup, spawn the SharedWorker, and then close the popup. But this is very intrusive for the user.

I tried to use sandboxed iframes but as soon I add the `allow-same-origin` directive the iframe starts sharing the process with its parent window.

Is anyone aware of any other solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I went through some of my own apps and saw that the way I went around this
or what I did similarly working with `Chrome`, was by creating a new window and creating an iframe running on that. (which I know you don't want but is kinda hard to do without) If you could create 2 pages with half the data running on one and then the rest on the other page could work too. **Another solution** *I somewhat tested but don't know if it fully works* is loading the first round of data and placing it into your DOM (Assuming you have HTML or some kinda of generator), closing your `noopener` and `sharedWorker` or `serviceWorker` as you said, and then loading the other half after the first half is done loading (Creating or initializing a second `sharedWorker` or getting more data.). You could potentially do that like I was doing through a small `chain of functions`.

Note: I assumed you have a DOM because Chrome apps have some sort of HTML or DOM most of the time.

Hope this Comment if you somewhat get the idea or need further knowledge :)